# Python 2 string somehow saved as pure Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have the following strings in Chinese that are saved in a following form as "str" type:
`\u72ec\u5230`
`\u7528\u8272`

I am on Python 2.7, when I print those strings they are printed as actual Chinese characters:

```
chinese_list = ["\u72ec\u5230", "\u7528\u8272", "\u72ec"]
print(chinese_list[0], chinese_list[1], chinese_list[2])
>>> 独到 用色 独
```

I can't really figure out how they were saved in that form, to me it looks like Unicode. The goal would be to take other Chinese characters that I have and save them in the same kind of encoding. Say I have "国道" and I would need them to be saved in the same way as in the original `chinese_list`.

I've tried to encode it as utf-8 and also other encodings but I never get the same output as in the original:

```
new_string = u"国道"
print(new_string.encode("utf-8"))
# >>> b'\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x81\x93'
print(new_string.encode("utf-16"))
# >>> b'\xff\xfe\xfdVS\x90'
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: it doesn't have to have 2 Chinese characters.

EDIT2: Apparently, the encoding was `unicode-escape`. Thanks @deceze.

```
print(u"国".encode('unicode-escape'))
>>> \u56fd
```

Comment: The encoding is called `unicode-escape`, e.g. `u'国道'.encode('unicode-escape')`. However, this will produce a string with a backslash, a "u" and numbers and letters. Which is different from a string literal `"\u72ec\u5230"` in source code; that string literal contains two Chinese characters expressed in a string literal unicode escape sequence, not a backslash, "u" etc… So, it's somewhat unclear what you want exactly.

Comment: @deceze what do you mean by "string with backslash"? It doesn't have to have 2 characters, this was just the example I had.

Comment: @deceze looks like it was `unicode-escape` after all, thanks a lot!

Comment: The shown code only works on python3, not python2.

Comment: @deceze I see that it output backslash twice for some reason: `print(u"国".encode('unicode-escape'))` outputs `b'\\u56fd'`. I guess the initial backslash was deleted afterwards.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see, I messed up. I was apparently using Python 3! Now it works in Python 2: `print(u"国".encode('unicode-escape'))` outputs `\u56fd`, which is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\u....` is unicode escape syntax. It works similar to how `\n` is a newline, not the two characters `\` and `n`.

The elements of your list *never* actually contain a byte string with literal characters of `\`, `u`, `7` and so on. They contain a unicode string with the actual unicode characters, i.e. `独` and so on.
Note that this only works with unicode strings! In Python2, you need to write `u"\u...."`. Python3 always uses unicode strings.

The unicode escape value of a character can be gotten with the `ord` builtin. For example, `ord(u"国")` gives `22269` - the same value as `0x56fd`.
To get the hexadezimal escape value, convert the result to hex.

```
>>> def escape_literal(character):
...     return r'\u' + hex(ord(character))[2:]
...
>>> print(escape_literal('国'))
\u56fd
```